# Python: make sure to send 1024 bytes at a time

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

perl_server.pl

```
$client_socket = $socket->accept();

if (defined $client_socket) {
    $client_socket->autoflush(1);
    $client_socket->setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, pack('l!l!', 30, 0)) or die "setsockopt: $!";
}

    while (1) {
        my $line = "";
        $client_socket->recv($line, 1024);
        print "$line\n";
}
```

python_client.py

```
def random_line():
    return "random len of line here"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (brock_host, int(brock_port))
sock.connect(server_address)
while True:
    sock.sendall(random_line())
```

How do i gurantee so that perl_server receives line at a time (not mangled)?
Or prevent line from being buffered so it's not printing in the server side unless another line comes in?

i believe if i make sure the size of the item sent is 1024, then perl server would get a line at a time, correct?

How do i make sure if the line is 1024 bytes at a time?

whats a good strategy if the line is longer than 1024 bytes? (not sure if this is a case to be concerned about)

normally, a line would be somewhere around 50 characters

Comment: sendall does it for you,

Comment: @self let's say the line has 1524 bytes, sendall() will send 1024 bytes and 500 bytes. server can read 1024 bytes fine but it will be blocked at 500 bytes, correct? or does sendall guarantee to send 2x 1024 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PACKET_SIZE = 1024
line = random_line()
sock.send(line+"\x00"*max(PACKET_SIZE-len(line),0))
```

is one way you could do it

another way (if `'\x00'` is **not** your terminal char)

```
'{val:{terminal}<{size}}'.format(val=line,size=PACKET_SIZE,terminal='\xff')
```

Comment: yes, this case will work if the line has less than 1024 bytes. i think i need to  break up the line if the line is more than 1024 bytes and send two 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a combination of using stride, length, and padding. `max` isn't needed as you are sure the slice is smaller than your packet size.

```
M = 32

for length in (M - 1, M, M + 1):

    payload = '1' * length

    for i in range(0, len(payload), M):

        packet = payload[i : i + M]

        packet += '0' * (M - len(packet))

        print(packet)

print()
```

Output:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110

11111111111111111111111111111111

11111111111111111111111111111111
10000000000000000000000000000000
```